# document library validation formula

Tags: document, library, validation, syntax

I have a CATEGORY column which has 4 choices (A, B, C, D) and is mandatory.

I have a second column (lets call it TYPE) which can have content (but is not mandatory).

What I want the validation to do is determine if user puts any text in the TYPE column, I want it to validate that it is CATEGORY C or D.   If the CATAGORY is A or B, I want type to be left blank.

whats the proper validation syntax to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Formula:

```
=IF(Category="Checklists",IF([Checklist Categories]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

User message:
*If Category option Checklists is selected, you must also make a selection for Checklist Categories.*

I struggled with the same issue, and I was never able to get it to work, I was trying to do the validation from the column definition. I finally tried the same code from the VALIDATION SETTINGS IN THE LIBRARY SETTINGS and it worked like a charm. In my example, if you choose "*checklists*" (a choice field) then you must fill out "*checklist categories*" (also a choice field)